# como accecer a dos posiciones iguales en dos arreglos distinos en php

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, web

**arreglo A**

```
[
  {
    "estado": "a"
  },
  {
    "estado": "b"
  }
]
```

**arreglo B**

```
[
  {
    "dato": "1"
  },
  {
    "dato": "2"
  }
]
```

Los dos arreglos siempre tendrán el mismo tamaño. Usé dos `foreach` para recorrerlos pero el resultado no es lo que se espera. El resultado que obtengo al momento de imprimir estado y dato fue `a1,a2,b1,b2` y es lógico que sea así pero lo que yo quiero es que sólo imprima `2`.

Ej: `estado:a el dato:1 , estado:b el dato:2` y no así las diferentes combinaciones

**Resultado esperado**: `estado:a ,dato:1` y `estado:b ,dato:2` ya que el del estado a su valor es 1 y estado b su valor 2. ¿Alguna recomendación? De antemano gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Nos puedes decir qué has intentado? Te recomiendo leer [ask], hacer el [tour] (y ganar así tu primera medalla) y aprender a hacer un [mcve].

Comment: <?php for($i=0;$i<=count($arregloA);i++){echo $arregloA[$i]; echo $arregloB[$i];} ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero aclaremos un asunto del tema de los arrays asociativos. Cuando vemos un array como el que planteas (es un json, pero se puede interpretar como array), realmente tienes algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
[
  "0": {
    "estado": "a"
  },
  "1": {
    "estado": "b"
  }
]
```

O lo que es lo mismo, tienes un array de objetos, que cada uno de ellos es accesible por la clave 0 o 1. Si hubiera mas elementos, tendrias mas claves asociadas Y continuas.

aclarado esto, y aceptando la condicion que comentas de que cada uno de los arrays tiene el mismo numero de elementos, puedes recorrer uno de los arrays con un foreach con clave, esto es:

```
foreach ($arregloA as $key => $value) {

}
```

Dentro de ese bucle, podrías asignar a uno de los arrays el  valor del otro array, puesto que coinciden las claves:

```
$ArregloA[$key]["dato"] = $arregloB[$key]["dato"]
```

De esta manera tendrás en cada uno de los items del **arregloA** la clave 'Estado' y la clave 'Dato'

el codigo completo seria:

```
foreach ($arregloA as $key => $value) {
   $ArregloA[$key]["dato"] = $arregloB[$key]["dato"]
}
```